# Cloud Storage: Is there any way to notify users of a change made offline?

Tags: synchronization, cloud, storage, offline

If I have a Google Doc on my phone(which is currently offline) in which I make some changes & then, if I access the  same Google Doc through my laptop(which is connected to the internet) , is there some mechanism by which  I can be notified of the change I made on my phone when I was offline.

After searching I found ideas like let the phone(which is offline) connect to another device which is connected to the internet via Bluetooth etc and then send a notification/message via this device which is connected to the internet.
Is this really feasible?
Are there any other alternative or innovative ideas out there to solve this problem?